# Replace a magnetic Hall sensor with Arduino

Tags: arduino

I would like to use a motorcycle speedometer, tachometer for Sim Racing. The speedometer uses a 3-wire magnetic Hall sensor.

I am trying to use an Arduino to read game data and send it to the speedometer. Using a relay circuit works, but its clicking is extremely loud. The relay is used to close the ground wire to the two other wires.

Can this be done just using an Arduino to create a ground loop, or is there a relay circuit that is silent or something else I could use that I am unaware of?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1iT3d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An open-collector transistor driving the clock input.*

Assuming that your working relay contact is wired between HALL IN and GND of Figure 1, then a simple open-collector NPN transistor should do the job. Pretty much any small signal (and small package) NPN transistor will do the job.